# How to find out Angular Component Tree?

Tags: angular

I am a Angular beginner, I am working on a Angular 9 codebase; Angular Universal.

As Augury is not working for my web app, I need some help with understanding component tree structure. Please.

The components declared in app.module.ts under

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [ ]
})
```

are all of the declared components necessarily be called out in the app.component.html.

In my web app I see only one declared component called out in the app template. Is there anyway I can find out the component tree structure or where they are called out.

Comment: I would say look at the routing file

Comment: okay. Thank you so much. Will check that out.